# Importing classes from another file in Python

Tags: python

I've recently started learning Pygame (a Python module). My Pygame project is getting quite lengthy now - so much so that it is difficult to navigate. With previous python projects, I have been able to simply store most of the functions in separate python files, which the main file then imports.

Eg, in the main file:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
import second_file
second_file.run()
```

And in the second file:

```
def run():
   screen.fill([0, 255, 255])
```

I want to store a function in the second file, but this function needs to be able to interact with the *same* Pygame window as the main file. When it tries to do this currently, it returns an error message telling me that the name of the main file's screen is not defined.

Any help on how I could get around this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The example does not reflect the issue. There is no `screen` in this example. Anyway, you need to passe `screen` the the function. e.g.: `def run(screen):` and `second_file.run(screen)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How would you solve this issue if the function were in the same file, rather than being imported?

Comment: Have the functions in the other python file take arguments. Then when you call them pass the values you want as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing such a thing. Probably the best way to do this would be to **pass the screen as a parameter to the function** like so:
The second_file:

```
def run(screen):
   screen.fill((0, 255, 255))
```

And in the main:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
import second_file
second_file.run(screen)
```

Or alternatively you could basically make the **screen global and import it from the main file**. But I do not recommend this method. And if you do choose this method watch out for circular importing (main imports from second_file and second_file imports from main).